# Ideas on a PvP campaign

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I'm a young DM, and I need ideas for a PvP campaign. I am currently overwhelmed by trying to make a campaign and I need a little more time. I have 4 players, all level 3. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Unlike severa other sites and forums on the internet, Stackexchange works best with very defined questions about specific problems. Any question asking for opinions or possibly infinite lists (i.e. any question that does not have a single "right" answer) is not suited for our format. Take the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and read our [help] for more info on how the site works

Comment: I've edited for readability, but we need more information to be able to help. What classes do your players play? Why do you want to do PvP? What are your players' opinions? Have you played any sessions yet? If you add this information, then you should have an answerable question and it will be reopened :)

Comment: Honestly, even with that information @Dakeyras I would question whether it would make it answerable

Comment: @Phil if we have an detailed description of a situation and the asker needs advice with a part of it, that should be fine. If it's **clear what they're asking** and **not too broad**, then I don't see why we can't help

Comment: @Dakeyras "Ideas for a PvP campaign" is too broad a question, unless it is under very tight constraints (like our character generation questions). Those constraints don't appear to be here. The asker is probably better off asking this somewhere that supports discussion.

Comment: In fact I expect that if those constraints were listed, the asker would just end up describing the campaign they want to have, and arrive at their answer - unless there is a problem with that campaign, and *that* is something we can help with.

Comment: @Kittysrule I had a similar question as well: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/30068/pc-vs-pc-team-campaigns